# before submitting form data to database change some field data in view django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi my form is like this , And when I submit it goes to view I attached , I want to change for example add dashes between string in name field before it is submitted. So how I can do this in my view ?

> Form.html

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='The name of this map.')

subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,
                            help_text='If(unbolded)')
```

And when I I submitt it goes to that view

> View.py

```
def save_form_if_appropriate(self, attr):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            if self.site_acl >= self.acl.ADMIN or self.is_modifying_self(attr):
                if self.form.is_valid():
                    if attr == 'user':
                        obj = self.form.save(commit=False)
                        # this way we can keep record of the users creator.
                        obj.parent_id = self.request.user
                        if hasattr(obj, 'user_type') and obj.user_type != 'pro':
                            obj.sub_users_allowed = 0
                        obj.save()
                    else:
                        self.form.save()

                    messages.success(self.request, 'Thing saved.')
                    return True
                else:
                    messages.warning(self.request, self.form.errors)
                    # messages.warning(self.request, 'Thing was invalid, and couldn\'t be saved.')
            else:
                messages.warning(self.request, 'You don\t have permission to save that thing.')
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_form_if_appropriate(self, attr):
    if not self.request.method == 'POST':
        return False

    if not (self.site_acl >= self.acl.ADMIN or self.is_modifying_self(attr)):
        messages.warning(self.request, 'You don\t have permission to save that thing.')
        return False

    if not self.form.is_valid():
        messages.warning(self.request, self.form.errors)
        return False

    obj = self.form.save(commit=False)
    if attr == 'user':
        # this way we can keep record of the users creator.
        obj.parent_id = self.request.user
        if hasattr(obj, 'user_type') and obj.user_type != 'pro':
            obj.sub_users_allowed = 0

    # Here you can do whatever you want on the object
    # For example joining string in names
    obj.name = '-'.join(obj.name.split(' '))

    obj.save()
    messages.success(self.request, 'Thing saved.')
    return True
```

Comment: I got like that 'obj = self.form.save(commit=False)
                        then  name = obj.name'